# How do I return an instance of that Class using interface?

Tags: java, oop

```
interface Upgradable {
    returnVALUE PlantUpgrade();
}

public class Sunflower extends Plant implements Upgradable {
        Sunflower PlantUpgradable () {
      //somecode
      return NewSunFlower;
    }
}
```

Hi, how do I set the return value in the interface, so that the classes who use this object will have different returnvalue and its return value would be an object.

Comment: Try a generic interface `interface Upgradable<T extends Plant> { T PlantUpgrade(); }`, and `Sunflower extends Plant implements Upgradable<NewSunFlower>` with method `NewSunFlower PlantUpgradable () { return new NewSunFlower(); }`

Comment: Ahh Ic thanks. Didnt know if it was possible